# code dependent on object in java

Tags: java, oop

I need to get different code executed dependent on the object of my java class.

Further explanation: I am trying to create a "conversation" for a textadventure whith an NPC where the NPC tells you something and you have a few choices of what to say. Basically there are NPCs that have more to communicate with the player but there are of course NPCs that have more or less speechparts than others. So i can't really hardcode it with so many parts and just change the Strings from object to object like this:

```
public class NPC {
  private String[] speech;
  private String[] reply;

  public conversation() {
   speech[0];
   getReply(reply);
   speech[1];
   getReply(reply);
   speech[2];
   getReply(reply);
   ...
  }
}
```

And for example NPCone has 3 speech parts and NPCtwo has 7 and everyone of these parts does react in a certain way to different replys so i can't really use if or any loops either.

So i need a way to do this or work around it (hopefully without loosing the ability to put it all in one class), but maybe i'm just stupid here and can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: One class is all you need, but you're right, you can't hardcode the texts. What you need to do is put the conversations in a file for example, and have the NPCs load their own conversation. This of course requires you to spend some time designing the "conversation engine".

Comment: Maybe [Chain of Responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) with some [commons-chain](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-chain/cookbook.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does NPC stand for? And btw: java conventions suggest to not use abbreviated class names. And I wouldnt need to ask if your class would be NotPitoresquelyConfuser or somethin' alike ...

Comment: @GhostCat NPC = NonPlayerCharacter

Comment: @GhostCat NPC stands for non player character

Comment: @Kayaman how can i do that? I mean how can i get the conversation to work then?

Comment: @VictorGubin i thought about that too but if it is possible id like to avoid that because it would be one heck of a class with thousands of if clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a finate state machine. [FSM Theory and Implementation in game developmet](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finite-state-machines-theory-and-implementation--gamedev-11867)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but why can't you do:

```
public conversation() {
  int i = 0; 
  ...
  while(hasSpeech()) {
    speech(i);
    getReply(reply);
  }
```

Meaning: if you have repetitive tasks, then think up ways that allow you to use some sort of loop construct.

Comment: I cant do that because you get different reactions from the npc depending on what you reply to them.. i thought about that but i cant seem to make it work

Comment: Sure. I think the FSM is a good idea. Btw: welcome to upvote levels ;-)